# Codeplex Excel Data Reader give empty Data set for Excel 2010

Tags: c#, excel, codeplex

I’m using Codeplex Excel Data Reader to read an excel. The problem that I face is It reads Excel 97-2003 documents without any difficulty, but when reading Excel 207-2010 documents using ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream), it output’s an empty data set. Did anyone faced this problem. And is any one has any solution for this?

The read method is as follows

```
private DataSet ReadExcel(string fileName, string extention)

{

    DataSet dsData = null;
    FileStream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    IExcelDataReader excelReader = null;

    try
    {

        if (extention.Equals("xls"))
        {
            //1. Reading from a binary Excel file ('97-2003 format; *.xls)
            excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
        }
        else
        {
            //2. Reading from a OpenXml Excel file (2007 format; *.xlsx)
            excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
           // excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
        }

        excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = false;
        dsData = excelReader.AsDataSet();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (excelReader != null)
        {
            excelReader.Close();
        }
    }
    return dsData;
}
```

Comment: It was last updated in Aug 25 2009 , why dont you just reference the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application` and read it that way?

Comment: Initially I did that way, but I got following error "Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 8000401a.". It seems to fix this at least user needs to logged in to the server to initialize the excel service. But that is impossible, since server was located in a server farm and due to security issues client do not like to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8000401a indicates it was something to do with `Run As Logon Failure`.

Steer clear of [server-side automation of office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757). Or use XML to work with Excel spreadsheets on the server.

According to the [support issues with the Excel Data Reader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/releases/view/31934):

> Design and usage are great. So far only issue I've had is with certain
>   XLSX file not parsing correctly (reading in wrong sheets, missind cell
>   values, etc). To resolve these issues, I had to rebuild Excel.dll
>   using latest SharpZipLib from
>   http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Download.aspx. As
>   others have said, project needs an update, but is still good.

Or just use the standard micrsoft way:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
Workbook wb = null;
try
{
wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath, false, true,5,null,"WrongPAssword");
}

foreach (object possibleSheet in wb.Sheets)
   {
   var aSheet = possibleSheet as Worksheet;
     if (aSheet != null)
     {
....
```